# Como fechar app quando pressiono o botão back nativo do android?

Tags: android

Queria saber como faço para encerrar o aplicativo quando pressiono o botão back nativo do android estou usando este método:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Atenção");
        dialog.setMessage("Tem certeza que deseja fechar o app?");
        dialog.setNegativeButton("Não", null);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                System.exit(0);
                finish();
            }
        }).create();
        dialog.show();
    }


}
```

Meu app tem uma tela de login que identifica pelo campo login se o usuário é comum ou admin, se for admin o fluxo é redirecionado para a sessão de crud e se o usuário for comum o fluxo é redirecionado para um `listView` onde o usuário poderá verificar os itens na lista e a única ação que ele poderá fazer é encerrar o app. Só que ao clicar no back Button a mensagem do alertDialog é mostrada e ao invés do app encerrar ele volta para a tela do crud, já usei `finish()` e `System.exit(0)` mas nenhum dos 2 encerra o app.

Abaixo segue a classe principal onde recebo os valores da login pelo Bundle redireciono o fluxo dependendo se for usuário comum ou admin.

```
public class principal_Activity extends Activity {

    Button  btnListaClientes,
            btnCadastraEmpresa,
            btnListaEmpresa,
            btnCadastraPromocao,
            btnListaPromocao;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String adm = bundle.getString("usuario");
        if (adm.equals("admin")){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal);

        }else{
            Intent i = new Intent(principal_Activity.this, lista_promocao.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }


        btnListaClientes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnListaClientes);

        btnCadastraEmpresa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCadastraEmpresa);
        btnListaEmpresa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnListarEmpresas);

        btnCadastraPromocao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCadastraPromocao);
        btnListaPromocao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnListaPromocao);



    }

    public void listaCliente(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(principal_Activity.this, listaClientes.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public  void cadEmpresa (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(principal_Activity.this, cadastra_empresa.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public  void listEmpresa(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(principal_Activity.this, listaEmpresas.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public  void cadPromocao (View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(principal_Activity.this, cadastra_promocao.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public  void listPromocao(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(principal_Activity.this, lista_promocao.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    public void mensagem(String titulo,String texto){
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogo= new AlertDialog.Builder(principal_Activity.this);
        dialogo.setTitle(titulo);
        dialogo.setMessage(texto);
        dialogo.setNeutralButton("Confirma",null);
        dialogo.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Cara faz muito tempo que não mexo com Android, mas tentar matar a aplicação que eu me lembre é uma má prática. Deveria voltar para a tela de login, agora eu só não tenho a receita para te fornecer de como fazer isso, tem que dar uma pesquisada a respeito da ordem das activities e como encerrar ou pular para uma determinada activity da sequência. Espero não ter falado nenhuma besteira rs.

Answer (score 1):

Chame o método back pressed e finalize a atividade com `finish()`. Caso esteja em um fragmento, chame por `getActivity().finish()`

É muito importante você ter em mente que ao iniciar uma nova atividade em seu app, finalize sempre a atividade anterior... Com isso, sempre que o usuário pressionar o back pressed o aplicativo será  encerrado...

Comment: Deu certo velho, muito obrigado, era realmente o ciclo das outras activitys que ainda estavam em execução, OBRIGADO!!!!

Comment: De nada.... fico feliz em ajudar..... se vc  puder marque a minha resposta como a melhor encontrada. ai eu ganho reputação.....